# Querying with parent-child relationship in where clause

Tags: soql, rest-api

I'm trying to get Lead details for all leads that have product of interest like "Some Product" AND their status is "Act now" AND one of their campaign names is "bar" or "baz".

And in code:

```
SELECT Id, name, Company, Email, Status 
FROM Lead 
WHERE Product_of_Interest__c INCLUDES (%27Some Product%27)
AND Status = %27Act Now%27
AND Id IN (
SELECT Campaign.CampaignMembers.LeadId FROM Campaign 
WHERE Campaign.Name LIKE %27%25bar%25%27 
OR Campaign.Name LIKE %27%25baz%25%27)
```

I am getting the following error (returns status code 400):

> Didn't understand relationship 'CampaignMembers' in field path. If you
> are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the
> '__r' after the custom relationship name.

When I query `/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Campaign/describe` I get

```
'activateable': False,
 'childRelationships': [{
....
....
{'cascadeDelete': True,
   'childSObject': 'CampaignMember',
   'deprecatedAndHidden': False,
   'field': 'CampaignId',
   'relationshipName': 'CampaignMembers'},
...
```

So it is clear that `CampaignMember` is a child of `Campaign`.
I would have preferred to go around this issue, but the `Lead` object does not contain any information about campaigns.

How can this be solved?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't go down then up in a field path, so `Campaign.CampaignMembers.LeadId` will never work. However, you can do your filter join on `CampaignMember` instead, and it should work.

```
SELECT Name, Company, Email, Status 
FROM Lead 
WHERE Product_of_Interest__c INCLUDES ('Some Product')
AND Status = 'Act Now'
AND Id IN (
    SELECT LeadId FROM CampaignMember
    WHERE Campaign.Name LIKE '%bar%'
    OR Campaign.Name LIKE '%baz%'
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked.
However, I didn't understand what you mean by "go down and then up in a field path".
Could you please explain further?

Comment: You tried to go *down* to `CampaignMembers` then *up* to `LeadId`. Once you've referenced the child relationship it's a `List<SObject>` and you can't reference any fields on it.